# Did Rav Menachem Mendel Lefin (author of the book Cheshbon HaNefesh) view Kabbalah as nonsense?

Tags: biography

Rabbi Menachem Mendel Lefin is known mostly for his book Cheshbon HaNefesh. While researching biographical notes about him, I came across the following sentence on Wikipedia:

> He campaigned in favor of adding general education to the standard curriculum in Jewish schools, and he was a fierce opponent of the Hasidic movement and the Kabbalah, which he viewed as "nonsense."

You can find the quote here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menachem_Mendel_Lefin

Whoever wrote that line did not provide a source and so I'm asking if anyone knows of a source to back up the idea that Rabbi Lefin "was a fierce opponent of the Hasidic movement **and the Kabbalah, which he viewed as "nonsense."**

Comment: Your title asks about kabbalah in general, the body about kabbalah and hassidut. One can be opposed to the latter but not the former. Consider clarifying.

Comment: is this on-topic? this seems to be a question about an historical figure?

Comment: He might have been affiliated with members of the Haskalah and the Reformation.

Comment: would make sense he would be against those things. as an early leader in the haskallah movement he likely thought many aspects of Judaism to be nonsense

Comment: @Bach that a question is about an historical figure doesn't render it off-topic. This question is about Judaism (also), so is on-topic.

Comment: @Laser123 Is it true that being a maskil necessarily meant that you rejected kaballah (the Zohar) or that you viewed kaballah in general as nonsense?

Comment: I thought that being a maskil generally meant that you wanted a synthesis between "traditional" Judaism and modern "western" ideas. That does not necessarily mean rejecting kaballah, although it might.